# Why mongoose enum accepts non-array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose enum method (in mongoose schema) accepts non-array value. Ideally it should throw an error if  value does not match to the enum array. I cannot find any issue in my code for this unusual behavior of enum.

here is how I create Schema :-

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   role: {
    type: String,
    emum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
});
```

How I create User using this sehema:-

```
const newUser = await User.create({
   role: req.body.role
})
```

My request body in Postman :-

```
"role": "anything"
```

This is what I got response:-

```
"user": {
            "role": "anything",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

Comment: It's `enum` but not `emum`..

Comment: omg. it was a typo. I wasted my 3 hours to get rid of this. thank your.